# How to create an instance of GoogleAppsScript.Document.Text

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, mocking, google-docs, clasp

I want to unit test this code, which is Typescript transpiled using Clasp into Google App Script:

```
function onLinksInText(text: GoogleAppsScript.Document.Text, onLink: OnLinkCallback) {
    const iterator = new TextIterator(text, onLink)
    const characters = text.getText();
    for (let i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        iterator.handle(i, text.getLinkUrl(i));
    }
    iterator.end()
}
```

To do that, I need to create an instance of `GoogleAppsScript.Document.Text`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

You will have to mock the class.

**Long answer**

To successfully test the function, you only need the constructor, [`getText`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#gettext) and [`getLinkUrl`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#getlinkurloffset) methods mocked. Let us also mock [`setText`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#settexttext) for good measure:

```js
function TextFactory() {

  const linkMatcher = /https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:\.{0,1}(?:\w|-)+)+/ig;

  let private = "";
  
  return {
    setText(text) {
      private = text.toString();
      return this;
    },
    getText() {
      return private;
    },
    getLinkUrl(offset) {
      const idx = private.search(linkMatcher);
            
      if(idx < 0 || offset > idx ) { return null; }
      
      return private.slice(idx);
    }
  };
}

const mock = TextFactory();
mock.setText("Find me at https://example.com ");

console.log(mock.getText());
console.log(mock.getLinkUrl(4));
console.log(mock.getLinkUrl(12));
```

I assume `TextIterator` is your custom class, so, for demonstration, I made a simple shallow mock:

```js
function TextFactory() {

  const linkMatcher = /https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:\.{0,1}(?:\w|-)+)+/ig;

  let private = "";
  
  return {
    setText(text) {
      private = text.toString();
      return this;
    },
    getText() {
      return private;
    },
    getLinkUrl(offset) {
      const idx = private.search(linkMatcher);
            
      if(idx < 0 || offset > idx ) { return null; }
      
      return private.slice(idx);
    }
  };
}

const mock = TextFactory();
mock.setText("Find me at https://example.com ");

class TextIterator {

  constructor(text, onLink) {
    this.text = text;
    this.callback = onLink;
  }

  handle(index, link) {
    this.callback(`${link} at index ${index}`);
  }

  end() {
    console.log("ended");
  }
}


function onLinksInText(text, onLink) {
    const iterator = new TextIterator(text, onLink)
    const characters = text.getText();
    for (let i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        iterator.handle(i, text.getLinkUrl(i));
    }
    iterator.end()
}

onLinksInText(mock, console.log );
```

**References**

1. `Text` class [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text)